# connect to internet via two proxy server

Tags: internet, proxy, connection

I used to connect to internet in my foundation via proxy server with all usually required setting (IP, port, user name, password), but I want to hide my original IP by use another rented proxy server with different setting (another IP and port.... etc)

However when I use Firefox, for instance, I can in network setting set only one proxy server that used in my foundation to connect to the Internet but there is no place to set the another subsequent rented proxy server.

At my home there is no problem because I connect directly via WiFi and I use LAN settings to set the rented server proxy that used to hide my IP.

How can I solve the problem and use my proxy server from behind my foundation's proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed, and this is.not something you can do in your browser. Also, proxy servers can go some way to anonymising your traffic, but cant totally anonymise traffic, especially with most sites going to HTTPS (which is.not proxy friendly)

If you want to add multiple levels of protection you may want to look at a VPN. If you connect to your proxy across a VPN it will give you your second layer of protection and anonymity - and because it uses different mechanisms to a proxy it provides an additional type of security.  (It isbtechnically possible to nest VPNs, but probably not a gret idea).

Altermatives would be to run your own anonymising proxy on a VPS you purchase anonymously or usong TOR or TAILS or similar. All these techniques have limitations.  Also,  you should bgoogle Panopticlick if you are not aware of it, as your browser itself gives up a lot if information, proxy or not.